# How do I describe people who don't have enough time?

Tags: word-usage, meaning, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

How do I describe people who don't have enough time? Would "time-constrained" do? Is it even a word to begin with?

> Unfortunately, she was ***time-constrained*** and let things slide.

Comment: Everyone who's not immortal is constrained by time.  But it sounds like you're describing someone who's *busy*, *has a lot to do*, *has a full plate*, *has a full dance card*, etc.

Comment: It would depend on the context and the cause of time constraint. As you already mentioned, a generic way to say is "she _didn't have enought time_".  _Time-constrained_ is a word but it is normally not used for people, it is used for abstract/intangible concepts like process, cycle, project etc. Some other options depending on the context/nuance: "had a limited time", "was tied-up", "was pressed for time" etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Time-constrained is a word but it is normally not used for people, it is used for abstract/intangible concepts like process, cycle, project etc. Some other options depending on the context/nuance: "had a limited time", "was tied-up", "was pressed for time" etc. - @ermanen

As some have mentioned in the comments, "she didn't have enough time" is perfectly fine and generic. If you want a **word** for it, then "time-constrained" is actually fine. Other alternatives are:

- Unfortunately, she had a **limited time** and let things slide.
- Unfortunately, she was **in a rush/hurry** and let things slide.
- Unfortunately, she was **against the clock** and let things slide.

Comment: By "time-constrained" I meant "too occupied by something else so not having time to adequately allocate it to whatever is implied by the sentence". Is this knowledge going to affect your answer?